# How to pick dates that have all 24 hours in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file which is something like below

```
13,2018-02-11 11:40:13.553385+00:00,CDA,10.4.100.1,KDE,2.0,3.0,4.49,0.0,,,,,,,,
14,2018-02-11 12:00:13.586360+00:00,CDA,10.4.100.1,KDE,2.0,3.0,12.16,0.0,,,,,,,,
15,2018-02-11 12:00:28.452263+00:00,CKD,100.100.100.1,LMF,0.0,19.0,0.12,0.0,,,,,,,,
16,2018-02-11 12:00:33.123310+00:00,CKD,100.100.100.1,LMF,0.0,19.0,1.28,0.0,,,,,,,,
17,2018-02-11 13:00:37.793817+00:00,CVC,100.100.100.1,KDE,0.0,19.0,2.5,0.0,,,,,,,,
18,2018-02-11 13:05:42.461774+00:00,CDA,100.100.100.1,KDE,0.0,19.0,2.79,0.0,,,,,,,,

19,2018-02-12 00:20:33.553385+00:00,CVC,10.4.100.1,KDA,2.0,3.0,4.49,0.0,,,,,,,,
20,2018-02-12 00:30:13.586360+00:00,CVC,10.4.100.1,KDA,2.0,3.0,12.16,0.0,,,,,,,,
21,2018-02-12 01:10:28.452263+00:00,CKD,100.100.100.1,LMF,0.0,19.0,0.12,0.0,,,,,,,,
22,2018-02-12 02:00:33.123310+00:00,KDE,100.100.100.1,CKD,0.0,19.0,1.28,0.0,,,,,,,,
23,2018-02-12 03:00:31.793817+00:00,LMF,100.100.100.1,CDA,0.0,19.0,2.5,0.0,,,,,,,,
24,2018-02-12 03:05:22.461774+00:00,LMF,100.100.100.1,CDA,0.0,19.0,2.79,0.0,,,,,,,,
...........................................................
..........................................................
44,2018-02-12 23:05:22.461774+00:00,CVC,100.100.100.1,KDE,0.0,19.0,2.79,0.0,,,,,,,,
44,2018-02-12 23:55:22.461774+00:00,CVC,100.100.100.1,KDE,0.0,19.0,2.79,0.0,,,,,,,,
```

If you observe, for the date `2018-02-11`, the data entries are only between `11` to `14`.However for the date `2018-02-12`, we have all the dates right from `00` to `23`.

How to check if a date has all `24` hours in this case `2018-02-12` in pandas?

I know how to add extra hours to make the date have `24` hours for which I do something like this

```
df = pd.read_csv("metrics_copy.csv", parse_dates=["date"])
df.set_index("date", inplace=True)

a = df2.resample('H')["cpu"].mean().dropna()
# create all posible hours by first min and max value floor to 0 and 23 hour
rng = pd.date_range(a.index.min().floor('d'),
      a.index.max().floor('d') + pd.Timedelta(23, unit='h'), freq='H')
# get all missing index values - missing hours
diff_idx = rng.difference(a.index)

# join new DataFrame with missing values to original, last sorting for correct ordering
df2 = pd.concat([df2, pd.DataFrame(index=diff_idx, columns=df2.columns)]).sort_index()
```

But I need to check if a date has `24` hours or not.How can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to make sure that for a given date, there is at least one data point for each hour 00-23? You could consider having a tracker that, as you read the CSV, it restarts when it hits a new date, then tracks when it hits a new hour (or makes sure it starts at 00), and if the new hour that it hits is not one more than the hour it was tracking, or if it hits a new date without getting to hour 23, then the date does not have data for all 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties)

```
df["date"].dt.hour.groupby(df["date"].dt.date).unique().apply(len).reset_index(name="count").query("count==24")
```

Comment: perfect!this is what I needed!Thanks!